# Any detailed documentation about the Chameleon Template in Pyramid Web Framework?

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

There's only a brief introduction to Chameleon Template in document of pyramid.

Any detailed documentation/tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the official docs [here](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: Thx! And another little question: I found that many templates are using 'metal:'. Does it have any relation to 'tal:' ?

Comment: @ymfoi, METAL is the macro part of the language.

Comment: Gotcha! So it seems that the Pyramid itself does have invoked a lot of other functional packages, doesn't it?